# Python compatability issue - 'in <string>' requires character as left operand

Tags: python

I make no claims to know anything at all about writing Python scripts or programming in general, but I've been tasked with writing one anyway that will have to operate on a wide variety of Python versions.  I wrote, and did my testing on versions 2.3, 2.4 and all went well.  Version 2.2 though is giving me fits and my google-fu must be weak because I'm coming up short with an answer.

The section of code that's giving me problems:

```
commandnum = 0
for commandloop in arguments[0:]:
    if "java" in arguments[commandnum][0]:
        for argloop in arguments[commandnum]:
            if "Dcatalina.home" in argloop:
                instance = argloop.split("/")
            elif "-Xms" in argloop:
                xms = argloop.split("Xms")
            elif "-Xmx" in argloop:
                xmx = argloop.split("Xmx")
            elif "-XX:MaxPermSize" in argloop:
                permsize = argloop.split("=")
            elif "Dcatalina.base" in argloop:
                home = argloop.split("=")
                appdir = home[-1]+"/webapps"
                warfiles = []
                for war in os.listdir(appdir):
                    if fnmatch.fnmatch(war, '*.war'):
                        warfiles.append(war)
                thefiles = ",".join(warfiles)
        try:
            instance
        except NameError:
            instance = None
        if instance is not None:
            print "%s %s %s %s %s %s" % (instance[-2], xms[-1], xmx[-1], permsize[-1], appdir, thefiles)
    commandnum = commandnum + 1
```

I understand that this is *UGLY* and probably a *BAD* thing, but the error that I'm getting is in the string matching using 'in'.  From what I gather by googling, in Python 2.2 you're limited to one character for string matching using 'in'.  What is the equivalent way in 2.2 to match on a string?

Upgrading machines to a modern version of Python is out of the question.

Any help/abuse is appreciated.  Try to be gentle as this is the first thing of any size I've written outside of shell scripts and MS Basic on my TRS-80 CoCo in 1981.

Comment: What is `argloop`? A list of strings?

Comment: Yes.  I should have elaborated more.  My task is to take the output of a 'ps -ef', search the output of the 'CMD' field for instances of 'java' and then grab info from it.  'arguments' is a list so that arguments[0][0] is the first item in the first line of the CMD field from the 'ps -ef' output. Once I start looking at the list for the first line in the CMD field, I loop through looking for things like 'Dcatalina.home' and '-Xms'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`str.find`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), which returns -1 if the substring cannot be found.

```
>>> s = "The quick brown fox"
>>> s.find("The")
0
>>> s.find("brown")
10
>>> s.find("waffles")
-1
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  That appears to be the direction I need to go.  I really appreciate everyone's answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can always match using regular expressions. It's been a while since I used 2.2, so I can't recall if `re` is available, or if you need to go back to `regex`, but I'm sure the docs on the python site will go back far enough.

Update: it looks like [re](http://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/lib/module-re.html) is available.